# Database Table for Items have same relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

How should I design a database for car parts.

The problem is that one car part like radiator can fit several cars. How should I resolve that problem?
Lets say I have a table like the one below:

**SKU#   Part           Make     Model     Year                Quantity**
H111    Radiator      BMW         E46            1998-2002        5 
H222    Radiator      Toyota     Corolla      2002-2004       2

The Radiator with SKU#H111 can fit two cars. One is which is shown in the table above "BMW E46 1998-2002" the other one is "BMW E39 2003-2004".

If I add two of the same part in the database table I will have problem because if I sell the part I will have to manually also delete the other one. 
I want to design the database so the part SKU#H111 have connection with two items. When I sell on of them the quantity of both item should decrease.

Comment: have you considered using a car/radiator association table ?

Comment: read about db normalization

Comment: have separate tables for `car`, `part`, `car_part`.  the `car_part` should hold an ID for a car model and a part model.  the quantity of parts would most likely go in the part table... however, if each part has an individual reference number/id... you might want two part tables.  `part_model` and `part` where `part_model` holds generic information and `part` holds info specific to an individual, physical item. you would then get quantity through aggregation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three tables:

- Car: columns ID, Make, Model, Start_Year, End_Year
- Part: columns ID, SKU#, Name, Quantity
- Car_Part: columns Car_ID, Part_ID

This is called *normalization*. To determine which parts go with which cars, you do a 3-way join.

```
SELECT sku, name, make, model, year, CONCAT(Start_Year, '-', End_Year) Years, Quantity
FROM Car c
JOIN Car_Part cp ON cp.Car_ID = c.ID
JOIN Part p ON p.ID = cp.Part_ID
```

If you need this query frequently, you can put it in a view.

Comment: What is the best way to insert data from the Car and Part table into the Car_Part table. Lets say I have a Part which fits two cars. How or which SQL-command I should use?

Comment: `INSERT into Car_Part(Car_ID, Part_ID) VALUES (car1ID, partID), (car2ID, partID)`

Comment: I also want that every Part should have images. Lets say I want to upload 0-12 images for a part. How should I design the database table? How should the images how association with specific Part?

Comment: Add a table Part_Images, with columns Part_ID, Image_Filename. To get the images for a part, you join the Part and Part_Images table.

Comment: You need to get yourself a good textbook on database design. This Q/A format is not an effective way to design a database. Don't ask me for recommendation, I have no idea what's out there.

Comment: Is it necessary to add a column Part_Images_ID? Or it is better without that column? I thought that it is for no use to have that column.

Comment: It's up to you. Some database designers put an ID column in every table, to ensure there's a primary key, and allow for referencing the table in other relation tables. I'm not fastidious about it.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help point you in [the right direction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a additional table to set a relation between the part and cars where these part is used:
for example:

```
Table: sku_id_car_model
SKU#    #Id Car Model
H111    BMW E46 1998-2002
H111    BMW E39 2003-2004
```

So, when you use the part, make an update in the quantity searching by SKU# and #Id Car Model

```
update car_parts 
set quantity = quantity - 1 
where sku_part = 'H111'
and concat(make, model, year) in (  select id_car_model 
                                    from sku_id_car_model 
                                    where sku = 'H111' );
```

It's an option,